# Player accidentally takes another players hand, is this a misdeal

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

Texas-Hold-em Player accidentally took another player's hand (pocket Aces) immediately to his left and looked at it, other player said that is my hand and player said do you just want to take my hand and player awkwardly agreed not knowing that he was giving up pocket aces. Player who played other players pocket aces went on to win a large pot.  Should that have been called a misdeal or the player who took the wrong hand should have just mucked his hand and passed the cards over to the player who rightfully had the hand??

Answer (score 4):

No misdeal. It is security risk to have a misdeal because of players actions, opens up a whole can of worms, that hustlers will take advantage of.

I do not know by your post if the players cards were intermingled, if they were the hands are clearly dead.

Having said that I would rule both hands dead. The solution the players worked out is absurd. You cannot play another players hand and if there is so much confusion as to who's cards are whose nothing is clear. The players did not protect their hands, so no one knows including the players involved, if the cards are at the proper player.

And as an aside, the player who looked at the pocket aces then suggested they trade hands, is a scumbag angle shooting player whom should be kicked out of home games, and not be played with and talked much about as the fleabag they are at a public casino.

Comment: Yes, as a floorman I would have ruled both hands dead immediately, or, if the player who picked up the cards still had his correct hand on the table easily identifiable, then I kill the hand he picked up and allow him to play the correct one, exposing the cards he picked up to the table.